# Finished Loading Resource Information. Rendering Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I was trying to add upload file button into UI. For that I changed swagger-ui.js. I got file upload button there but next time when I try to run the application, it shows this error. I replaced changed file with previous one but still it shows error. Please tell me what I need to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced swagger-ui.js with latest version of swagger UI. It is working now.